# Convert Textbox Positive Values to Negative Based on Option Button Selection

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I am working on an Excel userform with a textbox for the user to enter a dollar amount that was either received or given. That number is put into a spreadsheet cell after the command button is selected. I have two radio buttons, one is for money given and the other one is for money received.

I would like the user to enter a positive amount in the box and when the given button is selected it turns into a negative. When the received button is selected it will leave the box as positive.

Normally I would multiply something by -1 to turn it negative. I tried `userform.textbox.value = userform.textbox.value * -1`.

```vb
Private Sub InsTxtBox_AfterUpdate()

    GameLogUF.InsTxtBox = Format(GameLogUF.InsTxtBox, "$#,###")

    If GameLogUF.InsPlyrOptnBtn.Value = True Then
        GameLogUF.InsTxtBox.Value = GameLogUF.InsTxtBox.Value * -1
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you trigger the event. Put a breakpoint in this sub and try to change the value.

The **AfterUpdate** event is triggered when control or record is updated. Within a record, changed data in each control is updated when the **control loses the focus** or when the user **presses Enter or Tab**.

Just checked your code and it works if the event was triggered.

Also, I suggest to change it a bit.

```
Dim value As Double
Dim tryValue As String
'remove $ sign so String value could be converted to Number format
tryValue = Replace(GameLogUF.InsTxtBox.value, "$", "")

'if user input is not numeric after removing $ sign - input incorrect
If Not IsNumeric(tryValue) Then
    'do sth else
    Exit Sub
End If
value = tryValue

' "= True" part is not needed there is no need to compare boolean property '
If GameLogUF.InsPlyrOptnBtn.value Then
    'if user input is negative your code will turn it back to positive, with Abs it always will be negative in this case'
    value = Abs(value) * -1
End If
'do formatting in the end'
GameLogUF.InsTxtBox.value = Format(value, "$#,###")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked perfectly except I did need the boolean property to trigger it. I should have explained that one option box was for money going out and the other for money coming in so if the option box was selected for money going out it would turn the number into the negative. The code was perfect though. Thank you very much for your help I was stumped.